# MATCH returns #N/A even when a match exists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use an index-match function with multiple criteria, `VALUE_DATE` and `ISIN` since I have up to two different dates for each ISIN. however it returns `#N/A`. Testing the `=MATCH` function I see it returns an error even when a value exists.
My goal is it to return 7.50 in this case. I have confirmed that the data type for the dates are both `Date` and ISIN codes are both `General`.

I have supplied pictures of my table as well as my formula.
My formula is an array formula and I do use `{"Formula"}`. Error images:

[image: match error]

Match returns `#N/A` when 2nd element is `TRUE`.

[image: formula sheet]
My whole formula.

[image: table data]
The `tbl_data` source. As you can see the last two rows have identical ISIN code but different dates and I need to be able to differentiate between them.

Comment: it seems that you want to look up `ESG_SCORE` by two criteria: `Start Date` and `ISIN`. Why not try using **SUMPRODUCT** function? See [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/08/24/excel-sumproduct-function-formula-examples/#conditionally-count-cells) and if you still cannot work it out let me know I can do a solution for you.

Comment: Looks like you are matching the ISIN against a TRUE/FALSE value. Try: `INDEX(...,MATCH([@ISIN]&StartDate,tbl_Data[ISIN]&tbl_Data[VALUE_DATE],0))` As an array-formula

Comment: @M.Getrost I tried concatenating it but it still returns `#N/A`, when evaluating the formula it skips the arrays of `{0, 1, ... , 0}` and goes straight to the error.
@TerryW isn't the sumproduct the same as I am doing right now? Returning an array of 0's and a single 1.

Comment: Well, it tries to match "CH0012221716" against an array of 0 and 1's... Have you tried using the formula I provided?

Comment: @M.Getrost Thank you it works, it returned `#N/A` on my first attempt because there was no match for the `StartDate` in that particular instance, my mistake :)

Comment: @BlackBear Great!

Comment: @M.Getrost Would you post a comment with the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you tried to match a String against an Array with True/False-Values.

This seemed to work:

```
INDEX(tbl_data[ESG_SCORE_ADJ],MATCH([@ISIN]&StartDate,tbl_Data[ISIN]&tbl_Data[VALUE_DATE],0))
```

This concatenates the ISIN and the Date and searches an Array, where each entry is the concatenation of the ISIN and Date.